# Music bot discord.js mentioning vcs

Tags: discord.js

How would i go about mentioning a voice channel so that a i can let the user specify what channel it wants the bot to do music in?

Any insight on being able to do this would be nice as you cannot mention voice channels so you cant do message.channels.mentions.first()

Comment: You can actually mention a VoiceChannel. `<#ChannelID>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the name f the voice chanel, or create an invite directly to that channel so that they can just click it and join the voice channel.

```js
const channelToFind = "general"; //name of the voice channel you wanna find, MUST be a VC.
const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.name == channelToFind);
const inv = await channel.createInvite();

message.channel.send(`Click on the link to join the VC: ${inv}`)
```

Comment: Yeah but i would like it so that instead its dynamic meaning a user could set this with a command such as !musicchannel (name)

Comment: Have you defined `args` anywhere in your code? If so, use that there.